# Need JavaScript validation and submission

Tags: javascript, html, dom-events

I have done certain amount of validation but cannot stop the form from submitting it. Please help me with the validation of other left fields. This is my code:

```
<form action="" method="post" id="contacts-form" onsubmit="return >
<fieldset>
<div class="field">
<input type="text" value="Name:" id="name" onfocus="if(this.value=='Name:'){this.value=''}" onblur="if(this.value==''){this.value='Name:'}" />`enter code here`
</div>
<div class="field">
<input type="text" value="E-mail:" id="email" onfocus="if(this.value=='E-mail:'){this.value=''}" onblur="if(this.value==''){this.value='E-mail:'}" />
</div>
<div>
<textarea cols="1" rows="1" id="message" onfocus="if(this.value=='Message:'){this.value=''}" onblur="if(this.value==''){this.value='Message:'}">Message:</textarea>
</div>
<div class="link"><a href="#" onclick="document.getElementById('contacts-form').reset()">Clear</a> &nbsp; &nbsp; <a href="#" onclick="document.getElementById('contacts-form').submit(validateForm();)">Send</a></div>'
```

**The Js code I used is this:**

```
function validateForm()
{
var x=document.forms["contacts-form"]["email"].value;
var atpos=x.indexOf("@");
var dotpos=x.lastIndexOf(".");

if (atpos<1 || dotpos<atpos+2 || dotpos+2>=x.length)
{
alert("Not a valid e-mail address");
return false;
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 change onsubmit="return >
         onsubmit="return validateForm();"
```

and also close the form and fieldset tags like these < /form > < /fieldset >

Answer (score 0):

Do it like this:

Replace `onsubmit="return >` with `onSubmit="return validateForm();"`

and

Replace

```
<div class="link"><a href="#" onclick="document.getElementById('contacts-form').reset()">Clear</a>    &nbsp; &nbsp; <a href="#" onclick="document.getElementById('contacts-form').submit()">Send</a></div>
```

You now execute the validateForm on submit and if it fails the `onSubmit` gets the `false` from your function and will not submit/reload the site.

I'm not sure if it is necessary but you may also put a `return true` in your function after the if.

Comment: you're welcome! It would be great if you could accept this answer so others with a similar problem are able to find this - thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this (it may have some errors, cause I was writing it without checking):

```
function validateForm(){
var x=document.forms.contacts-form.email.value;
var atpos=x.indexOf("@");
var dotpos=x.lastIndexOf(".");

if (atpos<1 || dotpos<atpos+2 || dotpos+2>=x.length){
    alert("Not a valid e-mail address");
    return false;
}
else {
    document.forms.contacts-form.submit();
}
}
```

and html:

```
<form action='' name='contacts-form' method='post'>
<fieldset>
<div class="field">
<input type="text" value="Name:" id="name" onfocus="if(this.value=='Name:')            {this.value=''}" onblur="if(this.value==''){this.value='Name:'}" />`enter code here`
</div>
<div class="field">
<input type="text" value="E-mail:" id="email" onfocus="if(this.value=='E-mail:')        {this.value=''}" onblur="if(this.value==''){this.value='E-mail:'}" />
</div>
<div>
<textarea cols="1" rows="1" id="message" onfocus="if(this.value=='Message:')        {this.value=''}" onblur="if(this.value==''){this.value='Message:'}">Message:</textarea>
</div>
<div class="link"><a href="#" onclick="document.getElementById('contacts-vform').reset()">Clear</a> &nbsp; &nbsp; <button value="Send" onclick="validateForm()"></div>
</fieldset>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

try like this:

```
function validateForm()
{
var isValid =true;
var x=document.forms["contacts-form"]["email"].value;
var atpos=x.indexOf("@");
var dotpos=x.lastIndexOf(".");

if (atpos<1 || dotpos<atpos+2 || dotpos+2>=x.length)
{
alert("Not a valid e-mail address");
isValid= false;
}
retrun isValid;
}
```